# Sum formulas work in separate Evaluate functions but not combined

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I might be either doing a stupid mistake or am not aware of some strange limits of the VBA `Evaluate` function. Trying to calculate the following:

```
miSheet.Range("A1").value = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(IF('WS1'!$AA$7:$AA$1000000=""product"",IF(OR('WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""b"",'WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""C""),1,0)))-SUM(IF('WS1'!$AA$7:$AA$1000000=""product"",IF('WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""c"",1,0)))")
```

For some reason the two `SUM`s work in separate `.Evaluate` functions and deliver the expected output. Can you please help?

Note: I use a German version of Excel - all the functions seem properly translated and `;` is exchanged for `,`

Comment: you can't use `OR` in an array type formula as it will return only one response not an array like you want.  So instead of `OR('WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""b"",'WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""C"")` do `('WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""b"")+('WS1'!$AB$7:$AB$1000000=""C"")`

Comment: But why are you counting where it is `c` just to subtract it later?

Comment: And this can all be done with a countifs or two.

Comment: I don't think the {OR} is the problem as this sum works separately fine.

Comment: You can think that all you want, but OR does not work properly in array formulas.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I changed the formula to {miSheet.Range("A1").value = Application.Evaluate(=COUNTIFS('WS1'!$AC$7:$AC$1000000,""=product"",'WS1'!$AJ$7:$AJ$1000000,""=a"")+COUNTIFS('WS1'!$AC$7:$AC$1000000;""=product"",'WS1'!$AJ$7:$AJ$1000000,""=b"")-COUNTIFS('WS1'!$AC$7:$AC$1000000,""=product"",'WS1'!$AJ$7:$AJ$1000000,""=c"")")} - (there has been a problem in the above one), but it still produces #value. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe I should add that i use a German version of Excel. But all the functions seem properly translated and ";" is exchanged for ",". Still can't make sense of it.